# Recycle view not displaying data on the first instance

Tags: java, android

Recycle view not displaying data its shows an empty screen, It displays data when I go back and click the icon again. Not sure why I'm facing this problem.Please check the activity, adaptor and fragment code below. I'm new to android and I'm doing my capstone project it would be great if you can help me.

```
public class AppDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle("App Details");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app);
    AppDetailsFragment newFragment = new AppDetailsFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.recordAppFragmentContainer, newFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}

public void refreshAppDuration(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AppDetailsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void onBackAppDuration(View v) {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Adaptor

```
public class AppDetailsAdaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AppDetailsAdaptor.ViewHolder> {
private List<AppUsage> mApps;
private Context mContext;

public AppDetailsAdaptor(Context context, List<AppUsage> apps) {
    mApps = apps;
    mContext = context;
}

private Context getContext() {
    return mContext;
}

@Override
public AppDetailsAdaptor.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    // Inflate the custom layout
    View appUsageView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_app_details, parent, false);

    // Return a new holder instance
    AppDetailsAdaptor.ViewHolder viewHolder = new AppDetailsAdaptor.ViewHolder(appUsageView);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AppDetailsAdaptor.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    // Get the data model based on position
    final AppUsage ch = mApps.get(position);

    // Set item views based on your views and data model
    viewHolder._appTextView.setText(ch.getAppName());
    viewHolder._durationTextView.setText(ch.getDurationInMinutes());
    viewHolder._dateTextView.setText(ch.getDate().substring(0,10));
    final String key = ch.getKey();
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mApps.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView _appTextView;
    public TextView _durationTextView;
    public TextView _dateTextView;

        super(itemView);
        _appTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rvs_app_name);
        _durationTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rvs_app_duration);
        _dateTextView =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rvs_app_date);
    }
}
```

}

Fragment

```
public class AppDetailsFragment extends Fragment {
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
ArrayList<AppUsage> appList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<AppUsage> appListTemp = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<AppUsage> appListAdaptor = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<AppUsage> appObject = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<AppUsage> appListDate = new ArrayList<>();
private AppDetailsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
private RecyclerView rvApp;
private RecyclerView.Adapter appAdaptor;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager eLayoutManager;
private EditText date;
private static final int   DIALOG_DATE_PICKER  = 100;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_app_list, container, false);
    rvApp = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rvAppList);
    rvApp.setHasFixedSize(true);
    eLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rvApp.setLayoutManager(eLayoutManager);
    appList = getAllAppRecords();
    appAdaptor = new AppDetailsAdaptor(getActivity(), appList);
    rvApp.setAdapter(appAdaptor);
    return rootView;
}
public ArrayList<AppUsage> getAllAppRecords(){
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference();
    ref.child("AppUsage").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            appObject.clear();
            HashMap<String,Object> app = null;
            Iterator<DataSnapshot> items = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
            while(items.hasNext()){
                DataSnapshot item = items.next();
                Log.e("Listener",item.toString() );
                app =(HashMap<String, Object>) item.getValue();
                appObject.add(new AppUsage(app.get("appName").toString(),app.get("durationInMinutes").toString(),app.get("date").toString(),item.getKey()));
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
    return appObject;
}
```

Comment: [notifyDatasetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())

Comment: Too much code here to cover all. But I suggest you diagnose by putting breakpoint at setAdapter() row, then open app first time, if it jumps in and still shows empty screen, maybe the fragment should be focused fixing.